# Can there be git commits, that point to the same tree?

Tags: git, git-commit

I know that multiple git-trees can point to the same blob. This happens, when we only change the filename and do a commit again. But can there be git commits, that point to the same tree? If yes, when does it occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure...... a commom one, without thinking too hard: when you revert revisions, if you end up with the same tree (or several along the way of reverting many revisions)... well, there you have it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's common. Here are some cases in which you can create new commits that point at the same tree with another commit.

1. Use `git commit --allow-empty` to create an empty commit that has the same tree with its parent. An empty commit does not have any changes.
2. `git commit && git revert` to create a revert commit that has the same tree with its parent's parent.
3. `git commit-tree ${foo}^{tree}` to create a commit that has the same tree with `foo`. `foo` is a commit-ish.
4. Based on the same commit, commit the same changes. Repeating the steps, you get different commits that point at the same tree.

Comment: Also: `git merge -s ours`.